# Apply filters (blocklayared) on search results - Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am holding a Prestashop website (ver. 1.6.1.4), and I'd like to apply filters (also known as the "blocklayared" add-on) on search results. Does someone knows how to do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: That would be very hard to achieve

Comment: There are a few problems with this. First of all, blocklayered works with categories, while search function searches for products globally. Second, the hook `actionProductListOverride` called in category controller is not being called in search controller. Third: even if it was called there, it wouldn't work, because blocklayered would ignore the search results, it would only respect the filters selected within the blocklayered module. In short: it is possible, but I doubt you'll find a free module for that. And it's very unlikely you'll get an answer, as it would be way too long.

Comment: I have only one category, "Products". Does that change anything ?

Comment: Well, no, that doesn't change anything, because again - `blocklayered` doesn't take into account your search results.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is it still possible to do (by editing blocklayared), or do I have to start a new module from zero ?

Comment: It's your choice, you can do it both ways, but it is going to be very tricky. I had to display blocklayered on the index page, and not in the category once for some project - that was a very tricky thing to do, but that was a few years ago, haven't looked at blocklayered since then, it may be easier now, though.